# How to pass foreign key to serializer when creating parent at the same time?

Tags: python, django

Just to preface, I'm a beginner and I realise my conventions may not be exactly standard so I would be grateful if you would correct me for anything I'm doing completely wrong.

Currently, my API is called using:

```
http:127.0.0.1:8000/weather/<latitude>,<longitude>
```

I am pulling weather data from some API, but also want to store it in a database at the same time. To represent the weather, I have two models, *Location* and *Currently* which hold the coordinates and weather information. In this case, the parent is Location.

My issue is I don't know how to pass the *Location* foreign key to *CurrentlySerializer*. In the code below I'm not passing it in at all and I receive the obvious "location field is required" error.

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Process latitude and longitude coordinates from URL
    coordinates = kwargs.pop('location', None).split(",")
    latitude = coordinates[0]
    longitude = coordinates[1]

    # Retrieve weather data.
    forecast = get_weather(latitude, longitude)
    currently = forecast['currently']

    # Serialize and confirm validity of data.
    location_serializer = LocationSerializer(data=forecast)
    if not location_serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(location_serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    currently_serializer = CurrentlySerializer(data=currently)
    if not currently_serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(currently_serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    response = location_serializer.data + currently_serializer.data
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ... some fields


class DataPoint(models.Model):
    ... some fields
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Currently(DataPoint):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'


class CurrentlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Currently
        fields = '__all__'
```

**services.py**

```
def get_weather(latitude, longitude):
    response = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/' +
                        settings.WEATHER_API_KEY + '/' +
                        latitude + ',' +
                        longitude + '/')
    return response.json()
```

Comment: can you give me an output of `forecast = get_weather(latitude, longitude)`?

Comment: I just editted in services.py into the main post. I'm using DarkSky, so the full response format is in their docs: https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast

Comment: Yeah, it's just a block of json returned by Dark Sky's API. So like:
{
    "longitude": x
    .... data
}

Comment: I just don't know why you using `ForeignKey` field, if you need to pass it..

Comment: Sorry I mean I want the parent key from Location to fill the "location" field inside of my Currently model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `Location` instance that you want to attach to `currently`, and assign the `Locations` primary key to the data.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Process latitude and longitude coordinates from URL
    coordinates = kwargs.pop('location', None).split(",")
    latitude = coordinates[0]
    longitude = coordinates[1]
    # Retrieve the Location by latitude and longitude
    location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude, defaults={'other': 'fields', 'to': 'add', 'on': 'create')

    # Retrieve weather data.
    forecast = get_weather(latitude, longitude)
    currently = forecast['currently']

    # Assign location.pk to currently data
    currently['location'] = location.pk

    # Serialize and confirm validity of data.
    location_serializer = LocationSerializer(data=forecast)
    if not location_serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(location_serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    currently_serializer = CurrentlySerializer(data=currently)
    if not currently_serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(currently_serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    response = location_serializer.data + currently_serializer.data
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: In my case, the location might not exist yet when querying the database. If that is the case, is there a way for me to create a Location entry and then assign location.pk as you did instead of raising Http404?

Comment: Hey, you can use `Location.objects.get_or_create(...)` to get the location if it exists, or create the Location if it doesn't exist.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Nice that worked pretty well. The only problem now is LocationSerializer is creating a second row instead of updating the one created by `Location.objects.get_or_create(...)`.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I just need to pass _location_ into the serializer.